# How can I prevent display:table-cell elements from floating?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of `li's` which has `display:table-cell` property in order to `vertically center` the text inside. I can not use additional markup for this. I can not use `line-height` as there may be multiple lines of text.

When I give the `li's` to  `display:table-cell` property, they `float` next to each other.

How can I force them to be below each other, like they would with `display:block?` Or I can't?

http://jsbin.com/orijam/1/edit

```
li {
  height:50px;
  border:solid black;
  vertical-align:middle;
  min-width:100px;
  display:table-cell;
}
ul {
  border:solid red;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: add `float: left;` to `li`

Comment: then i would loose the vertical align effect which i need.

Comment: I think it's not possible to keep `display: table-cell` and the `vertical-align` as well as making it appear as a block.

Comment: starting to look like its not :(

Comment: The `table-cell` display property sets an element to display just like a `<td>`. Table cells appear inline, *not* on separate lines. The only way for you to realistically achieve this using `table-cell` would be to apply additional markup (as given in @NathanLee's answer), giving the `li` elements a `table-row` display and the inner markup the `table-cell` display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `li`:s to `table-row` and move the `table-cell` styling to your `a` elements (assuming you have a `ul li a` setup) 
(written on phone)

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Sgg/

Edit2: If you're missing the `a`:s you could add them (or a `span`) using JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#menu li').wrapInner('<span></span>');
});
```

Comment: its only lis, no elements inside them, just text

Comment: I assumed it was a menu and thus would have at least an `a` in each `li`. Would it be impossible to add an extra `span` using JS? (I've updated my reply).

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table` instead of `display:table-cell`. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `span` tag instead.

```
<li><span>li</span></li>
<li><span>li</span></li>
```

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/tnbSX/3/).

**The HTML:**

```
  <ul>
    <li><span>li</span></li>
    <li><span>li</span></li>
    <li><span>li</span></li>
    <li><span>li</span></li>
    <li><span>li</span></li>
    <li><span>li</span></li>
  </ul>
```

**The CSS:**

```
span {
  height:50px;
  border:solid black;
  min-width:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;
}
ul {
  border:solid red;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul li {display:block;}
```

By inseting a span tag inside the li, you can make sure that you can keep the vertical alignment middle for the li's as well as make them appear to be block.

Hope this helps now.

Comment: People, read question before submitting answer. _I can not use additional markup for this_

Comment: correct if i could id add a span inside the lis and make it table cell

Comment: sorry, but that is the only solution if you want what you have mentioned. As you cannot acheive all the things with this particular issue.  Here is the fiddle that achieves what exactly you want. http://jsfiddle.net/tnbSX/2/ - I have updated the same in the answer. - @Morpheus

Comment: "Add a 'break tag' after each li"? Please don't teach people to write invalid non functional code.

Comment: I have updated my answer @powerbuoy. I have provided the solution with the span tag.

Comment: for my information, why do you dont want to insert any tag inside the `li`? If you are looking for the solution that you want, you have to insert a `span` tag inside it. - @user1721135